# pandas to_excel converts _x10e6 _ to ღ. How do I avoid this?

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, export-to-excel, delta-lake

I have been trying to create an excel file with several sheets from delta tables, however some of my column names include  _x10e6 _ which is apparently translated to ღ.
I have tried to use  encoding='unicode_escape' and  encoding='utf-8' without luck.
I cannot use xlsxwriter because I am appending to an existing file.

Does anybody know how I can keep _x10e6 _ in column names?

A part of the code I am using:

```
goldDF = spark.read.format('csv')\
    .option('header', True)\
    .option('delimiter', ',')\
    .load(file_path)

pandaDF = goldDF.toPandas()


with pd.ExcelWriter('/tmp/output.xlsx',mode='a', engine='openpyxl') as writer:  
    pandaDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, index=False)

dbutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/output.xlsx", "/mnt/delta_lake_path")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `_x10e6_` is an XML escape code for the character 0x10E6 which [equates](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x10E6/) to the Unicode character “ღ”.

In a similar case Excel would escape this as `_x005F_x10e6_`. It looks like openpyxl doesn’t do this so you could do it manually using the string `_x005F_x10e6_` or (for anyone reading this who isn’t constrained by the append mode requirement) switch the “engine” to xlsxwriter, which will escape it automatically.

Comment: Hi @jmcnamara, this solution worked for me previously but now the string ```_x005F_x10e6_```  is converted to the string ```_x005Fღ``` in excel. Do you know if something as changed and if there is any other way to keep the string ```_x10e6_``` when writing excel?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to rename that string to `_x 10e6_` or something that isn’t an XML escape.